# Class 'app\Models\Phone' not found in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I am trying ORM one to one relationship. I dont know why it cant recognize model class phone.
code as follows.

Phone.php
<?php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];


    public function Phone(){
        return $this->hasOne('app\Models\Phone');
    }
}
```

Phone.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Phone extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "phones";

    public function User(){
        return $this->belongsTo('app\Models\User');
    }
}
```

UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Phone;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function insert(){
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = 'BBB';
        $user->email = 'bbb@mail.com';
        $user->password = 'bbb@mail.com';
        $user->save();

        $phone = new Phone();
        $phone->number = "445566";
        $user->Phone()->save($phone);

        return "RECORDS ADDED";
    }

    public function show($id){
        $phone = User::find($id)->phone;
        return $phone;
    }
}
```

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get('insert',[\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class,'insert'])->name('user.insert');

Route::get('show/{id}',[\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class,'show'])->name('user.show');
```

Comment: have you tried: composer dumpautoload

Answer (score 0):

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];


    public function Phone(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Phone');
        
        //Better to use ::class notation for greater benefits with IDE
        //return $this->hasOne(Phone::class);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Phone extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "phones";

    public function User(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
        
        //Better to use ::class notation for greater benefits with IDE
        //return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }
}
```

Folder/directory is `app` but the namespace is `App`

So need to change `app\Models\Phone` and `app\Models\User` to `App\Models\Phone` and `App\Models\User`

Better yet, use `::class` notation for greater benefits with IDE - like easy navigation - not possible with string literals.

So instead of string literal `App\Models\Phone` import `use App\Models\Phone` statement and the `Phone::class`

Similarly for User import `use App\Models\User` and then use `User::class`

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix this

```php
public function User(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

here  fix  namespace `app` to `App` like that you need to fix all